# How do I restore itunes library onto another computer

Tags: itunes, backup, external-disk

I followed all the steps as suggested for backing up and restore iTunes library in the apple support website: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1751 but I have problems with the 'choose library' part in the last step. I clicked it and located my iTunes Media folder but all that happened was that it just opened the folder and showed me what I have inside and not restore it.

Comment: Which specific support document are you referring to? You have to select the folder from inside iTunes of course.

Comment: Hey Lily, have a look at my answer below. When you open the itunes media folder, you then need to **select the `iTunes Library.itl` file**. This file will then restore your library

Answer (score 6):

I'm just [echoing the Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1751) for anyone else who comes across this answer. I have used this process many times when moving or reformatting my computer:

---

### Process for restoring an iTunes library:

1. Quit iTunes.
2. Copy your iTunes folder from your external hard drive to whatever location you desire on your internal hard drive.
3. Open iTunes while holding down the Option key (Mac) or Shift key (Windows).
4. In the resulting dialog, click the Choose Library button.
   [image: iTunes - choosing another library]
5. Navigate to the new iTunes folder you just copied and **locate the `iTunes Library.itl` file**
6. Click Choose (Mac OS X) or Open (Windows)
7. iTunes will open and your iTunes Library will be restored.

Comment: Thank you very much, that just made my life a lot simpler!

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the iTunes folder you just moved to the internal hard drive, not the iTunes folder currently on your computer.

If you were backing up to a disc, you have to follow [these instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1382).